# Unwanted whitespace created by CSS transition animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was creating scroll triggered css animations, and I'm having trouble with my off screen transitions from the right. The animation works exactly how I want it to, but it's creating unwanted whitespace on the side of the page. The size of this white space seems to correspond to the transition I set, and doesn't go away until I've triggered all the animations on the page. Any ideas on how to remove this whitespace so that the elements are moving in from off the canvas?

Here is the link to my testing environment
http://lamp.cse.fau.edu/~zellis1/test/

```
/*Slide in right*/
.slidein-right{
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 750ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 750ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 750ms ease-out;
  transition: all 750ms ease-out;

  -moz-transform: translate3d(100px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(100px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(100px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(100px, 0px, 0px);

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.slidein-right.in-view{
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);

}
```

Comment: I don't want to be a grammar Nazi, but before delivering to the client (if that's what you are doing), you might want to change "faiulure" to "failure." (It's in the $10,000,000 dollar settlement section.) Also, where is the unwanted whitespace? I didn't notice anything problematic.

Comment: I still have the white space issues, but thanks for pointing that spelling mistake out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not related to css animation, one thing you could do to fix this, is to add overfrlow-x: hidden; to your body.

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding overflow:hidden and overflow-x:hidden to all the classes I felt might need it, but none of them are having the intended effect.  Would there be an issue if I had that overflow set in several classes?

Comment: To fix the issue you are having, adding overflow-x: hidden; on body should fix it, you don't need to add overflow-x on all of your classes, if it's not an absolute element then setting it on body should work.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried and it still wasn't working. I just realized that the .css files were cached or something because the changes I was making weren't being reflected on the page. Adding overflow-x:hidden ended up fixing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This guy here is always your friend when you get rogue white spaces coming out the woodwork:

```
 overflow: hidden;

 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow:y: hidden;
```

If the anomaly is directly to the right, then probably overflow-x will be the guy you want. I also recommend checking it out in other web browsers after to make sure it is completely solved.

Check Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE or Edge. Just to get a nice rounded out sample. Check it on a smartphone too. Sorry my background is QA, I'm just trying to install some bonus logic because consistency is key.

As part of this, I highly recommend pressing say F12 and directly editing the CSS on the page because it might be occurring on a different layer than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

As your are using transform to animate the elements and CSS specification for transforms (the method by which Animate.css moves the elements) specifies that elements should affect the overflow of the browser and hence the body overflows until all the transform animation are over.

you can add `overflow:hidden` (better `overflow-x:hidden` as you are transforming in x-direction only) on the containing element.

Add this CSS

```
animation-fix{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

and add class `animation-fix` to body and remove it on all animation completes.

you can do this by checking the number of divs with `.animation-element.in-view` class is equal to the number of divs with `.animation-element` class you have in html.

Comment: I made the animation-fix class and added it to the body tag, but also all my animation-elements, but it isn't having any effect on the white space. 

I tried adding a $element.removeClass('animation-fix') in the same section of my JavaScript that adds the in-view class, but for some reason it isn't removing it. Not really sure if that is causing an issue. I've also tried to add overflow:hidden to all the classes I thought would need it and nothing seems to be working. Any ideas why that is?